# When does Drupal 5 change the filename field in the system table?

Tags: 5

I tried to uninstall a module from my Drupal 5 website and now it has stopped working. It displays the .info files instead of the pages.

I can fix this temporarily by changing the "filename" fields in the system table from "module_name.info" to "module_name.module".  However this is a temporary fix.  It breaks when someone visits the website one or more hours later.

So I'm wondering what is causing Drupal 5 to change these system.filename fields?